# facebook like button bug (with cold cache)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm asking an advice on how to proceed to report the following bug:

***** I'm describing the bug as using 'private browsing' because it was how I could reliable reproduce it; the actual problem happens whenever the browser has a pure cold cache, like when cookies and everything is cleaned, for example

Start any browser in 'private browsing' mode, go (w/ cold cache) to any 'like button' URL, e.g.

https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/BatePapoUOL&send=false&layout=button_count&width=450&show_faces=false&action=like&colorscheme=light&font=arial&height=21

after clicking 'like', the page goes blank and some network error is logged on firebug's (and the like) network page.

The response header is the following (please note that its content-lenght is zero):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-WebKit-CSP: default-src *;script-src https://*.facebook.com http://*.facebook.com https://*.fbcdn.net http://*.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.google-analytics.com *.virtualearth.net *.google.com 127.0.0.1:* *.spotilocal.com:* chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://*.akamaihd.net http://*.akamaihd.net;style-src * 'unsafe-inline';connect-src https://*.facebook.com http://*.facebook.com https://*.fbcdn.net http://*.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.spotilocal.com:* https://*.akamaihd.net ws://*.facebook.com:* http://*.akamaihd.net;
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-FB-Debug: P5P8mjHfEje2BZgxUL+/gi9dj8+wrPR0zMMSlwrdAAo=
Date: Mon, 07 Jan 2013 19:08:53 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
```

I also tried to get a new code for my like button done @ this URL to no avail:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is being addressed by Facebook. More information available here

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/403206233093888